# Dockerfile: Combined run statements don't work correctly?

Tags: docker

I've encountered a fairly perplexing issue with a Dockerfile I'm working on.

I need to install nodejs into a Windows container. The following statements do this...

```
RUN powershell -Command Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://nodejs.org/dist/v12.18.0/node-v12.18.0-x64.msi" -OutFile "./node-v12.18.0-x64.msi";
RUN msiexec /i node-v12.18.0-x64.msi AGREETOLICENSE=yes ADDLOCAL=ALL /qn;
RUN powershell -Command Remove-Item ./node-v12.18.0-x64.msi;
```

In an attempt to optimise the size and number of layers, I tried changing it to this...

```
RUN powershell -Command Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://nodejs.org/dist/v12.18.0/node-v12.18.0-x64.msi" -OutFile "./node-v12.18.0-x64.msi"; \
    msiexec /i node-v12.18.0-x64.msi AGREETOLICENSE=yes ADDLOCAL=ALL /qn; \
    powershell -Command Remove-Item ./node-v12.18.0-x64.msi;
```

The reasoning was that it would then avoid caching a layer with the node installer in it.

This appears to work correctly, except then later in the Dockerfile when it runs a command which requires node, it complains that it's not installed.

I can't see any reason why this is happening. The two different versions should be equivalent, with the exception of having less layers.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing the following...

```
SHELL ["powershell.exe", "-Command"]

RUN $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; \
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://nodejs.org/dist/v12.18.0/node-v12.18.0-x64.msi" -OutFile "./node-v12.18.0-x64.msi"; \
    Start-Process msiexec.exe -Wait -ArgumentList '/i "node-v12.18.0-x64.msi" AGREETOLICENSE=yes ADDLOCAL=ALL /qn'; \
    Remove-Item "./node-v12.18.0-x64.msi"
```

After that, everthing worked fine.

I suspect that one of the commands was failing, but due to the way I was calling it, an error wasn't being thrown.

I think powershell might be the default shell, but I set it anyway to improve clarity.